# Powershell Formatting - Pipeline vs Control structure (?)

Tags: windows, powershell

I am still rather new to PowerShell and saw the two examples below and was wondering why they show two different results when, at least to me, they're seem to query for the same answer. Thanks ahead for the input.

```
get-host | select version
```

Vs.

```
(get-host).version
```

Comment: Compare this: `get-host | select version | fc` and `(get-host).version | fc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Host | Select-Object version` creates a custom object with a single property, `Version`, from the inputobjects which in this case is the output from `Get-Host`.

```
PS C:\Users\frode> Get-Host | Select-Object Version | Get-Member -MemberType Properties

   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost

Name    MemberType   Definition
----    ----------   ----------
Version NoteProperty version Version=5.0.14257.1000
```

`(Get-Host).Version` loops through the objects returned from `Get-Host` and extract/expands the value of the `Version`-property. This is the same as running `Get-Host | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version` or `Get-Host | Foreach-Object { $_.Version }`.

```
PS C:\Users\frode> (Get-Host).Version | Get-Member -MemberType Properties

   TypeName: System.Version

Name          MemberType Definition
----          ---------- ----------
Build         Property   int Build {get;}
Major         Property   int Major {get;}
MajorRevision Property   int16 MajorRevision {get;}
Minor         Property   int Minor {get;}
MinorRevision Property   int16 MinorRevision {get;}
Revision      Property   int Revision {get;}
```